# Cannot Tags and Groups fields in Webform CiviCRM Integration - Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, drupal-8

I try to create a contact in CiviCRM 5.9.1 with a **Webform** and **Webform CiviCRM Integration** (all in Drupal 8.6.7),

But when I choose the needed fields in CiviCRM and I use the **ENABLE TAGS AND GROUPS FIELDS** : no field appears.

If I still save then I get in Drupal an `Error: Class 'Drupal\webform_civicrm\CRM_Core_BAO_Tag' not found in Drupal\webform_civicrm\FieldOptions->get()`

To recover the use, I need to delete the Webform.
All of the other fields appears and can be selected in the Webform : Phone, Email, etc.

Is this, reveals a bug in Webform CiviCRM Integration or could it be something wrong in the Tags and Groups ?

Also if I select Yes for Tags and Groups fields, then impossible to get fields for Phone, Email, etc.

With Tags and Groups fields on No
[image]

With Tags and Groups fields on Yes, no other fields can be selected
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect d8 webform_civicrm does not yet have those fully functioning. KarinG is leading the project and would welcome assistance and/or funding I suspect. I think the most recent update is in this [blog](https://civicrm.org/blog/karing/webform-civicrm-integration-new-features-added-in-2018-and-looking-ahead-to-2019) where she says

> Drupal 8 port! The D8WFC project kicked off in August 2018 and we've already got Contacts, Memberships and ... Contributions working. Yes! We're transacting through live pathways. Try out the dev version: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/releases/8.x-5.x-dev if you feel adventurous: it currently contains Contacts and Membership functionality. If you want to try Contributions you'll need to check our GitHub repo:  https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/tree/8.x-5.x - and keep an eye on PRs against that branch

Comment: Thanks Pete. I will follow the lead and see what I can do for helping. Not sure I have enough knowledge…